# ClickHouse full scan elimination

Tags: clickhouse

I have the following table in ClickHouse

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dijkstra.stats
(
    name LowCardinality(String),
    timestamp DateTime64(9, 'UTC'),
    payload   Array(Float64)
)
    ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree()
        PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(timestamp)
        ORDER BY (name, timestamp);
```

When I run the following query, CH makes a full scan. Basically, I wan't to find the last meaningful value for a statistic name.

```
SELECT 0.5 * (payload[1] + payload[2]) as avg
FROM dijkstra.stats
WHERE name = 'stat_name'
  AND NOT isNaN(payload[1])
  AND NOT isNaN(payload[2])
  AND timestamp <= 1706871564.000000000
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

How to eliminate this full scan? In my understanding, if data are already sorted by `(name, timestamp)`, then the full scan is not needed, because we use the same column names in the WHERE clause.

Here is the query explanation.
[image]

EXPLAIN ESTIMATE result:
[image]

Comment: Could you share `EXPLAIN ESTIMATES` result?

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: looks like 
```
AND timestamp <= 1706871564.000000000
```

really need to scan the whole table because you have158 parts before `2024-02-02 10:59:24`

Comment: I don't understand this. Data is sorted. Why is full scan needed?

Comment: I mean query will full read and filter 3 columns, `payload` `name` and `timestamp`
and only `timestamp` will try to `prewhere` filter, but 159 parts , check explain (without estimates) again, you should see something like `159/159 parts`